# className as a function and use in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I came across those lines of code, I did not know classnames is a React library. What does it mean that it can act as a function? Can anyone help walk me through?

```
import cn from "classnames";  
interface Props {
    className?: string;
    children?: any;
    el?: HTMLElement;
    clean?: boolean;
}

const Container: React.FC<Props> = ({
    children,
    className,
    el = "div",
    clean,
}) => {
    const rootClassName = cn(className, {
        "mx-auto max-w-[1920px] px-4 md:px-8 2xl:px-16": !clean,
    });

    let Component: React.ComponentType<
        React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
    > = el as any; // this part is really confusing too! 

    return <Component className={rootClassName}>{children}</Component>;
};

export default Container;
```

Comment: Did you try reading https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames? _"what does it mean that it can act as a function"_ - it means it's a function...

Comment: Yea, I never thought it is a function, i thought it is just a class attribute like used in Html for css! I am still not sure why it was used like function in my question.... like is it to make the component container to be more resueable?

Comment: `className` _is_ an attribute (or a prop, anyway). `"classnames"` is the name of the library from which you're importing a function used to _generate_ the value of that attribute. They're related, but they're **not** the same thing.

Comment: i understand now it is a function, it takes the argument className and join the tailwind string to generate a value for className atttibute. I just never saw it before, i guess it is some sort of component template , in my code, it is trying to make all the container to return the same style right?if so,  this is like really a high level of design global style....

Answer (score 0):

The class names library is only a utility type library to join class names. Is basically a function where you can pass multiple arguments and it joins them together as a string (to be used as a classname). It has nothing to do with the react component classname attribute.

This code:

```
const rootClassName = cn(className, {
        "mx-auto max-w-[1920px] px-4 md:px-8 2xl:px-16": !clean,
    });
```

It's basically joining the classname string sent in props with the string `"mx-auto max-w-[1920px] px-4 md:px-8 2xl:px-16"` if the value of clean is not falsy

Comment: Hi thanks! I think I kinda get it. But why not just use <component className="tailwind stuff here">?

Comment: @jimzhou The readme of that library explains the benefits. You should read that. https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames But I think the best example use of this library is: `classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); // => 'foo bar baz quux'`

Comment: @AlexWayne yes, I mean I understand it now in theory, is there an youtube video show real world example to explain the benefit of it?

Comment: @jimzhou because you want to add some styles conditionally depending on the `clear` variable